# Scrolling Background

Tags: scroll, cocos2d-iphone, background-image

I'm trying out new things for a simple game in Portrait mode, I want to add a seamless scrolling background to a game, the image is 512x512px.

The Main scrolling I want to have is Vertically, but I want to be able to scroll sideways too within the bounds of the image size. How should I go about with this, I'm using cocos2d.
David

Answer (score 1):

Try repeating the texture (in this case within 2000px)

```
CGRect repeatRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Background.png" rect:repeatRect];
ccTexParams params =
{
    GL_NEAREST,
    GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR,
    GL_REPEAT,
    GL_REPEAT
};
[background.texture setTexParameters:&params];
```